# Basic Looping in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

i'am junior programmer student. so confuse with making loop program with output below with align right :

```
54321
 4321
  321
   21
    1
```

but i've try this one :

```
for (int i=1; i<=5;i++){
    for (int j=1; j<=i;j++) {
         System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k=i; k<=5;k++) {
        System.out.print(k);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But the output below (align right works):

```
12345
 2345
  345
   45
    5
```

How, I've 98 try edits the code, but keep fail. What should I do?

Comment: System.out.print(6 - k);

Comment: Or have your loop run from 5 down to 1. You can use - - instead of ++.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler version, using decrementing loops and the ternary conditional operator to choose whether to print number or space.

```
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 5; j > 0; j--)
        System.out.print(j > i ? " " : j);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your logic to this:

```
  for(int i=5;i>0;i--){ 
        for(int k=i;k>0;k--){
                System.out.print(k);    
            }
            System.out.println(""); 
        }
```

Comment: That will not print right-align, as OP mentioned. Question has been updated to make it more clear.